# Bash: Path with \

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to achieve something really simple here, but something is missing.

I'm trying to create a file via bash script (.sh).

When I try direct on my terminal:

```
touch /Users/luco/Downloads/My\ Test\ Folder/test.txt
```

It creates the .txt file without issues. However, when I try directly on my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
clear
touch "$1"/test.txt
```

It doesn't work. Gives me this message:

```
.../test.txt: No such file or directory
```

I'm calling the script in this ways:

```
./Script.sh "/Users/luco/Downloads/My\ Test\ Folder/"
./Script.sh /Users/luco/Downloads/My\ Test\ Folder/
```

None worked.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you calling the script?

Comment: What if you run it as `./the_script /Users/luco/Downloads/My\ Test\ Folder`?

Comment: The script given in your question does not exhibit the problem stated.

Comment: @chepner Updated! Sorry!

Comment: @Arkku Alredy tried. Didnt work.

Comment: ...so, when you use *both* quotes and backslashes, the problem is obvious -- don't do that.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy What you mean?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I also use without it, and doesnt work.

Comment: Try `printf '%s\n' hello\ world goodbye\ world`, and `printf '%q\n' "hello\ world" "goodbye\ world"`. The double quotes make the backslashes literal.

Comment: `./the_script "/Users/luco/Downloads/My Test Folder"` is exactly the same as `./the_script /Users/luco/Downloads/My\ Test\ Folder`. Both of these are different than what you get when you use *both* quotes and backslashes.

Comment: BTW, if you run `set -x`, this will make your shell print each command it runs before it runs it in unambiguous form. I'd suggest doing so, and comparing the `set -x` output with the working command against the `set -x` output with the broken one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using both quotes and backslashes at invocation time will produce the same error, using *either* this:

```
#!/bin/sh
touch "$1/test.txt"
```

...or this:

```
#!/bin/sh
touch "$1"/test.txt
```

---

The problem can be reproduced as such:

```
$ ./test.sh "/Users/admin/Developmemt/Pippo\ Pelo"
touch: /Users/admin/Developmemt/Pippo\ Pelo/test.txt: No such file or directory
```

I get the error (due to the backslash being inside quotes -- `"/"` -- thus meaning that a literal backslash is expected to be part of the directory name).

---

By contrast, if not using quotes, the backslash is read as a signal to the shell, not as a part of the directory name, so it works:

```
$ ./test.sh /Users/admin/Developmemt/Pippo\ Pelo
```